# PHP - How to use csrf token in multiple forms on the same page

Tags: php, forms, security, session

I have 2 forms on the same page. I want to use the csrf token in both forms. when I try to use it, it regenerates the csrf token on form submission.

How can I solve this?

```
<?php

function csrf_token() {
    return bin2hex(random_bytes(35));
}

function create_csrf_token() {
    $token = csrf_token();
    $_SESSION['csrf_token'] = $token;
    $_SESSION['csrf_token_time'] = time();
    return $token;
}

function csrf_token_tag() {
    $token = create_csrf_token();
    return '<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="' . $token . '">';
}

$csrf_token = csrf_token_tag();
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    ...
    <?= $csrf_token; ?>
</form>

<form action="" method="post">
    ...
    <?= $csrf_token; ?>
</form>
```

Comment: you need to scope it, i.e: `$_SESSION['tokens']['formName']['csrf_token']` etc, see [this](https://github.com/lcherone/cloud-developer/blob/master/app/framework/traits/csrf.php)

Comment: where is the code that "regenerates the csrf token" or the code to check csrf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refresh the page, the function `created_csrf_token` gets fired again, changing the CSRF token.

As Lawrence has commented, you can scope it. E.g.

```
<?php

function csrf_token() {
    return bin2hex(random_bytes(35));
}

function create_csrf_token() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['csrf_token'])) {
        return $_SESSION['csrf_token'];
    }
    $token = csrf_token();
    $_SESSION['csrf_token'] = $token;
    $_SESSION['csrf_token_time'] = time();
    return $token;
}

function csrf_token_tag() {
    $token = create_csrf_token();
    return '<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="' . $token . '">';
}

$csrf_token = csrf_token_tag();
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    ...
    <?= $csrf_token; ?>
</form>

<form action="" method="post">
    ...
    <?= $csrf_token; ?>
</form>
```

Adding an isset into the `create_csrf_token` will check if the CSRF token is set, and return the existing, rather than create a new one.

You probably want to add some logic though, to create a new CSRF token after around 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your help! any tips of regenerating the token?

Comment: Sure, store the date as something like `$_SESSION['time'] = strtotime(date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime("now")))` then do a comparison in/before the isset like `if (strtotime("-5 minutes") > $_SESSION['time'])` regenerate the CSRF

Comment: Thanks again! I have done something like: `if (!isset($_SESSION['csrf_token']) || strtotime('-5 minutes') > $_SESSION['csrf_token_time']) // generate a new token` if this condition is not true return the same token.

Comment: I can't see how this as shown would possibly work; the session never got started.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner It works! we regenerate the token after 5 minutes or if there is no CSRF token

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Do you have any better solution?